# Why does Spring Boot create beans of the same type regardless of any @Primary annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Configuration class that looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class MyDependencyConfig {

@Bean
@Primary
public MyDependency getMyDependency(){
    System.out.println("getMyDependency");
    return Mockito.mock(MyDependency.class);
}

@Bean
public MyDependency getMyDependency2(){
    System.out.println("getMyDependency2");
    return Mockito.mock(MyDependency.class);
}
}
```

And have elsewhere in my code:

```
@Autowired
MyDependency foo
```

Why is it when the application context starts up, my console prints

> getMyDependency
>
> getMyDependency2

when only the bean from getMyDependency() will be used? I am using spring boot-1.5.1.RELEASE

Thank you kindly,
Jason

Comment: You did not use lazy-loading on your beans so they get loaded wether you use them or not. Try to add `@Lazy` on top of `@Bean` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: `@Primary` annotation doesn't stop Spring from creating beans. It's been taken into account when dependencies being injected

Comment: Thanks @ArnaudDenoyelle. Just checked and marking `@Lazy` on both beans and does indeed result in only 
  getMyDependency
being printed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Spring configuration instantiates and loads all declared and required beans in the Spring container at the startup of the Spring context.

So, even if you don't use all beans defined in your configuration, the methods annotated `@Bean` in your configuration will be all invoked.

[The `@Primary` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) has another goal.

> It indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple
>   candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency. If
>   exactly one 'primary' bean exists among the candidates, it will be the
>   autowired value.

It is just a way to not specify systematically the `@Qualifier` annotation when you have more than one candidate bean.

For example in your case as one of two beans is specified as `primary`  :

```
@Bean
@Primary
public MyDependency getMyDependency(){
    System.out.println("getMyDependency");
    return Mockito.mock(MyDependency.class);
}
```

You don't need to specify the qualifier `"getMyDependency"` to inject which one specified as `primary` :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("getMyDependency")
MyDependency foo;
```

You can directly do that :

```
@Autowired
MyDependency foo;
```

While for the second one bean that is not specified as `@Primary` :

```
@Bean
public MyDependency getMyDependency2(){
    System.out.println("getMyDependency2");
    return Mockito.mock(MyDependency.class);
}
```

You have to specify `@Qualifier` to clear ambiguities when you want to inject it :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("getMyDependency2")
MyDependency foo;
```

---

Loading beans in a lazy way is not advised as it delays the catch of configuration errors. So, it is eager by default.

You have more details in the [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init) provided in your comment.

Now, if you want to prevent this default behavior and define a lazy initialization for a bean, you can alternatively specify the `lazy` `String` value in the `@Scope` annotation of the bean :

```
@Bean 
@Scope("lazy")
public MyDependency getMyDependency(){
  ...
}
```

or better you can annotate the bean declaration or all the configuration (if you want that all beans be lazy initialized) with a [`@Lazy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) annotation.

For a specific bean :

```
@Bean 
@Lazy
public MyDependency getMyDependency(){
   ...
}
```

For all beans of the configuration :

```
@Lazy
@Configuration
public class MyDependencyConfig {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the part in your docs that supports your post: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init

Comment: You are welcome. Good and clear reference, thank you.  I added it in a next part of the answer and I also presented two alternatives to bypass the default behavior with annotation based configuration.